# Extracting numbers Excel from string of texts

Tags: excel, formula

I have the following information in excel.

```
1 PT: 1 AS
25PT: 1 AS
1.03PT: 1.02AS
1 PT: 14AS
73 PT: 1 AS
1 PT: 1 AS
```

Each line is in a separate cell.  I want to extract the numbers into different cells. 
So, for instance:

- For the first line, Column I = 1 and column J = 1
- For the second line, Column I = 25 and column J = 1
- For the third line, Column I = 1.03 and column J = 1.02

Etc.

For column I used the formula:  `=LEFT(H5,FIND(" ",H5)-1).`  However, if there is no space between the number and the letter, the formula doesn't work.

For Column J, I used the formula: `=MID(H4,7,1)`.  However, if there is more than one letter it doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Use text to columns (twice, delimited, once by the letter `P` and once by "space")

Comment: Convert each string to a character array, get only the part that matches one of the {1,2,3...9, '.'} starting from the left. Concatenate into a string again.

Answer (score 1):

Use put in B1 and copy over one and down:

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"PT",""),"AS",""),":",REPT(" ",99)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*99+1,99))
```

[image]